# Why is setTimeout needed when applying a class for my transition to take effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element with a transition applied to it. I want to control the transition by adding a class to the element which causes the transition to run. However, if I apply the class too quickly, the transition effect does not take place.

I'm assuming this is because the `.shown` is placed onto the div during the same event loop as when `.foo` is placed onto the DOM. This tricks the browser into thinking that it was created with `opacity: 1` so no transition is put into place.

I'm wondering if there is an elegant solution to this rather than wrapping my class in a setTimeout.

Here's a snippet:

```js
var foo = $('<div>', {
    'class': 'foo'
});

foo.appendTo($('body'));

setTimeout(function(){
    foo.addClass('shown');
});
```

```css
.foo {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 5s ease;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.foo.shown {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, the point is not about the setTimeout, but about how the element is rendered.

The CSS transition will only appear if the element is rendered with a property value, and then this property is changed.
But once you `append` the element, it does not mean that it was rendered. Simply adding a `setTimeout` is not enough. Thought it may work for you, in some browser versions it won't work! (Mostly Firefox)

The point is about the element's render time. Instead of `setTimeout`, you can force a DOM render by requesting a visual style property, and then changing the class:

```js
var foo = $('<div>', {
    'class': 'foo'
});

foo.appendTo($('body'));

//Here I request a visual render.
var x = foo[0].clientHeight;

//And it works, without setTimeout
foo.addClass('shown');
```

```css
.foo {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 5s ease;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.foo.shown {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now you have additional unused variable in your code.

Comment: For me, I was adding a new DOM element, and so height didn't work.  I had to do element.getBoundingClientRect().  This is a great answer.

Answer (score 3):

When you do DOM manipulation that that javascript relies on immediately afterwards, you need to pause javascript execution briefly in order to allow rendering to catch up, since that will be done asynchronously.  All a blank setTimeout does is move the code within to the end of the current execution pipeline.  The browser must complete rendering the new layout before it will obey a trigger for your transition so the setTimeout is a good idea and in my opinion the most elegant solution.

Comment: Is this a common pattern, then? Or how does one normally transition in an element when it is first rendered on the page?

Comment: The CSS3 designers' mental understanding is different from how most people wishing to animate view it, and I don't think either is "wrong". CSS3 views it as "**When/if changing X style property style**, use this movement pattern" when most designers just want to control specifically "I want to define an animation, in which it **Moves from here, to here**." Sometimes it becomes a bit easier if you try to approach it with more CSS than JavaScript (ie, cater to their wishes).

Comment: *"since that will be done in a separate thread asynchronously"* Uh, I doubt that. JavaScript runs in the same thread, otherwise the UI wouldn't freeze for long running JS processes.

Comment: Yeah, wow, thanks Felix, I don't know where the separate thread part came from, clearly not true.  I just meant asynchronously.